# How do I structure a HOC Context with Firebase and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase

I'm using TypeScript in a React app which uses Firebase for authentication. Before using TypeScript, I was using a regular context for the Firebase part, which was fine.  However, now that I've added TypeScript I'm getting errors.

As an example, here is my SignIn component (some parts omitted for brevity):

```
import React, { Component }        from 'react';
import Firebase, { withFirebase }  from '../Firebase';

const SignInForm = (firebase:Firebase) => {

  onSubmit = event => {
    ... uses firebase to handle authentication ...
  };


  render() {
 
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       ... sign in form ...
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default withFirebase(SignInForm);
```

In ../Firebase I have index.js, which contains:

```
import FirebaseContext, { withFirebase } from './context';
import Firebase from './firebase';

export default Firebase;

export { FirebaseContext, withFirebase };
```

./firebase.js is:

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

class Firebase {

  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
  }

  getUserIdToken = () => {
    if (app.auth().currentUser !== null) {
      return app.auth().currentUser?.getIdToken() as Promise<string>;
    }
    return Promise.reject("User not signed in") as Promise<string>;
  };

  ... various other firebase functions ...

}
 
export default Firebase;
```

and ./context.js is:

```
import React    from 'react';
import Firebase from './firebase';

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext<Firebase | null>(null);

export const withFirebase = (Component: React.ComponentClass) => (props:any) => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {
      firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />
    }
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
)

export default FirebaseContext;
```

The Context Provider is at the top level, and looks like:

```
import React    from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Firebase, { FirebaseContext }  from './components/Firebase';
import App                            from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

The error I'm getting is in the export line of my SignIn component: `export default withFirebase(SignInForm);`.  The SignInForm is underlined and the error message is:

```
Argument of type '(firebase: Firebase) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>'.
  Type '(firebase: Firebase) => Element' provides no match for the signature 'new (props: {}, context?: any): Component<{}, any, any>'.
```

Hovering over the underlined error gives me the function definition:

```
const SignInForm: (firebase: Firebase) => JSX.Element
```

So, from what I can tell, the problem is that withFirebase is expecting to receive a Component, but is receiving a JSX element instead. Is there a way to convert the JSX to a Component before passing it in?  Or is there another way to approach this?

Comment: You have defined your `withFirebase`'s parameter to be `ComponentClass` and `SignInForm` is not, or is it? It seems to have render method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SignInForm` is very confused about what it is.  It's a function and not a class component, but it has a `render()` method rather than a `return` statement.  It doesn't accept the right arguments to be a function component.  It *should* accept a props object, instead it takes a single argument called `firebase`.  You need to fix `SignInForm` into a legitimate function component or class component.

```
const SignInForm: React.FC<{firebase:Firebase}> = ({firebase}) => {
    /* ... */
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       ... sign in form ...
      </form>
    );
}
```

```
class SignInForm extends React.Component<{ firebase: Firebase }> {
    /* ... */
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                ... sign in form ...
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

As it is currently written, your `withFirebase` HOC can only accept a class component.  You can easily fix this by replacing `React.ClassComponent` with `React.ComponentType`.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, I've gone through so many versions of this that it has become confused.  I'll untangle it!

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  I just added curly brackets around the firebase and it fixed it.